# Automatically create DDL for external tables (from s3) in snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have data in s3 bucket in parquet fomrat. I am creating a table in snowflake to read data from the S3 table , as I am reading them as external tables.

I created an external table as

```
create or replace external table CB_Aasa
( 
 uuid varchar(80) as ($1:uuid::varchar ),
name varchar(80) as ($1:name::varchar ),
  DATE_LOADED datetime as ( $1:DATE_LOADED::datetime ),
  SOURCE varchar(60) as ( $1:SOURCE::varchar ),
   filename VARCHAR(2000)as METADATA$FILENAME,
  date_part  varchar(20)  as substr(METADATA$FILENAME,25,10) 
)
partition by (date_part)
with location =@PI.C_STAGE/crun/acq
file_format = $parquet_file_format
aws_sns_topic=$sns_topic
auto_refresh = true ;
```

What is the easier for creating this DDL?

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Have you looked at using the combination of `INFER_SCHEMA` and `CREATE TABLE...USING TEMPLATE`?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema.html

Comment: Thank is it something like this 
select *
  from table(
    infer_schema(
      location=>'@mystage'
      , file_format=>'my_parquet_format'
      )
    );
but this will give all column names only.

Comment: Can you please show an example, in the doc you have given it gives only select example  NOt create table?

Comment: What do you mean by “easier”? What are you finding difficult about the SQL statement you’ve given?

Comment: Every time i need to write this entire ddl on my own   to get table structure, I thought if snowflake had a way to get coulmn names and datatype automatically from parquet file and wrap it into a create table stmt

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you wouldn't look at the `CREATE TABLE...USING TEMPLATE` in the docs, as well.  Here is that link:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax.  Use this and where it says <query> you enter the `SELECT` from the `INFER_SCHEMA` docs.

Comment: Read Mike's suggestion on INFER_SCHEMA.  The output is not just the column name, but the type, nullable, expression, and filetype https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema.html#output